# Display custom field if it has content or hide if not

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm displaying a custom field like this:

```
<div class="blog_text">
    <img src="<?php the_field('imagen_prensa'); ?>" />
</div>
```

I would like to make the img appear only if the user has uploaded an image, because right now if there is no image then a broken image symbol appears.

I have tried the following, but it did not work:

```
<?php if (get_field('imagen_prensa') != ''): ?>
     <img src="<?php the_field('imagen_prensa'); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any can this be achieved?

**EDIT:**

this is the code now using the answers below but now it gives just a blank page:

```
<div id="blog_interior">

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <article>
            <div class="article_date"><?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></div>
            <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
            <div class="blog_text">
                <?php if ( !empty(the_field('imagen_prensa')) ): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo the_field('imagen_prensa'); ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="video_prensa"><?php the_field('video_prensa'); ?></div>
                <?php the_content() ?>
            </div>
        </article>

        <?php endwhile; ?>    
            <div class="back">

            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the echo to actually print the result of the_field('imagen_prensa').

Use this:

```
<?php if ( !empty(the_field('imagen_prensa')) ): ?>
     <img src="<?php echo the_field('imagen_prensa'); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've edited your code, to something which seems a bit more logical also added echo's where they were missing. I'm not used to these constructions:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

So I'm not actually sure if it's working properly or not, but you could check what these variables output by surrounding them with a var_dump like var_dump(have_posts());

Your edited code:

```
<div id="blog_interior">

    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): ?>

        <div class="article_date"><?php echo the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></div>
        <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
        <div class="blog_text">
            <?php if ( !empty(the_field('imagen_prensa')) ): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo the_field('imagen_prensa'); ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="video_prensa"><?php the_field('video_prensa'); ?></div>
            <?php echo the_content() ?>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>    
    <div class="back">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this just gives me the same blank page, it doesn´t show any content now

Comment: @fxg I've edited your newly posted code, could you explain what the while part of your code is doing? Or var_dump the result of these variables. When u say white screen, I'm fairly sure your while loop isn't working.

Comment: @fxg glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 6):

[empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) empty — Determine whether a variable is empty

```
if (!empty(get_field('imagen_prensa'))) {
    // Display image
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using empty() instead of comparing with an empty string.

```
<?php if (empty(get_field('imagen_prensa')) === false): ?>
    <img src="<?php echo the_field('imagen_prensa'); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

empty() also checks for values like `null` or `false` which may be returned. You may also `trim()` the string if the field may contain only whitespaces.

Comment: You may dump the return value of `get_field('imagen_prensa')` using `var_dump()` or `print_r()` it may be no empty value (null, false, '', 0, ...)

Comment: As CE_REAL mentioned the echo was missing. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: now it just makes the page to stop loading... 500 internal server error when I put this code :S

Comment: I put an edit, see how I did it, this is just giving me a white screen

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you have set default image as [no image](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=no%20image%20icon&hl=en&tbo=d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Pp7RUK3NLbGfmQX_qYDYBQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAA&biw=930&bih=592) in user.
If user have uploaded image then display its own image.

See this link may be help you. [PHP: How to display a default Image if the specified one doesn't exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833282/php-how-to-display-a-default-image-if-the-specified-one-doesnt-exists)